# Manifolds of sets

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

Consider a set $M$ such that $M$ is a set of all countable subsets of a compact set $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^d$.Let $d(x, y)$ be the distance between two sets $x, y \in M$. For instance this could be the [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance). My question is: is the set $M$ a manifold? If yes, then how do I find a diffeomorphism between $M$ and a subset of $\mathbb R^m$ for some $m$? Or even show that such a diffeomorphism exists.

Comment: Note that $d(x,y)$ might ve zero for distinct $x,y$

Comment: How is that so when $d(x, y)$ is Hausdorff?

Comment: @user3364566:  What is $d(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Q}+\sqrt{2})$?

Answer (score 1):

Take $d=1$ and $\Omega = [0,1]$. Fix some countably infinite subset $X$ of $[1/2, 1]$ and for any given $n$, consider the subset $M_n$ say of $M$ comprising sets of the form $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\} \cup X$, where $0 < x_1 < x_2 < \ldots < x_n < 1/2$. Then (for any reasonable notion of distance between two sets) $M_n$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold topologically embedded in $M$. Since this holds for every $n$, $M$ cannot be an $n$-dimensional manifold for any $n$ (by [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain)).

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense. If we were to impose the additional constraint that $M$ is the set of all subsets of size $\leq k$ (for some $k \in \mathbb Z^+$). Then is there an obvious diffeomorphism? Or is this non trivial?

Comment: If you take $M$ to be the set of subsets of $[0, 1]$ of size exactly $k$ you'll get a manifold that is diffeomorphic with $\Bbb{R}^k$ via a diffeomorphism that shouldn't be too hard to describe (it's easy if you require $1/2(i+1) < x_i < 1/2i$, but without that constraint, it will be a bit more fiddly). If you allow finite sets of different sizes, then you won't get a manifold: try drawing a picture of what if you get if you allow the size to be $1$ or $2$.

Comment: As an aside: if you take $d = 2$ and look at the finite sets, you are looking at spaces that have been intensively studied in connection with the [braid groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braid_group).